# Heatmap on globe - distortion problems

Tags: geoserver, heat-map, epsg, globe

I want to display a heatmap (png) on a globe in an android app.
The heatmap is generated programmatically. The heatmap consists of colored circles. 
I upload the png to geosserver and display it as wms layer in my app. 
I use EPSG 4326 as projection to display it on the globe. 
Unfortunatly, the heatmap is distorted at the poles. It's shown in the picture. 
How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: +1 It's a good question.  This image should cause you to reconsider the validity of the original heatmap: the heatmap values always were grossly distorted--and now you can see why. The right solution ought to involve recomputing the heatmap. How to do that depends on what this "heatmap" really is: is it a kernel density estimate or is it something else?  (People use the term "heatmap" in different ways.)

Comment: Try picking an equal area projection and see if that helps.

Comment: (If anyone wants to explore this in R I recreate it here, requires a github package plus CRAN ones: https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/a3d2277bae7cd8082302)

Comment: I don't use kernel density estimation. I create the heatmap with php. I draw circles with different amounts of black depending on the weight of the coordinates on a canvas. 
After that every pixel is assigned a color depending on the grayscale of the pixel. 
How can I distort the circles for my purpose?

Comment: What you describe is an algorithm for a kernel density estimate.  Do you have the capability to modify the circle radii and densities according to where they are drawn on the map?

Comment: Ok. Yes, I can change the circle radius and I know its postion, because the center of the circle are given coordinates.

Comment: How do I have to modify the circle radius?